# Porquê «período» e não «periúdo»?

Tags: ortografia

Nunca compreendi a acentuação gráfica de *período*. Parece-me que *periúdo* estaria mais próximo da maneira como [toda a gente pronuncia a palavra](http://pt.forvo.com/word/per%C3%ADodo/#pt), à semelhança de [*miúdo*](http://pt.forvo.com/word/mi%C3%BAdo/#pt) ou *viúvo*, enquanto *período* sugere uma [pronúncia próxima de *varíola*](http://pt.forvo.com/word/var%C3%ADola/#pt)

Até ao princípio do século XX a palavra escrevia-se sem acento: *periodo*. Com o esquema de acentuação gráfica introduzido nas reformas de 1911 em Portugal e 1943 no Brasil (responsáveis pela maioria dos acentos que temos hoje) poder-se-ia argumentar que *periodo*, sem acento, só seria apropriado se a palavra rimasse com *iodo*. Será que o acento foi um subterfúgio para evitar este problema? Ou será que a palavra se pronunciava de maneira diferente nessa altura? Qual a razão da grafia atual?

Comment: Nunca tenho bem a certeza, mas acho que "cá no nuorte" dizemos mais "prí.u.do".

Comment: Não dirão antes *pri.ú.do*, rimando com *miúdo*? Cá em baixo o ***e*** na primeira sílaba também vai à vida.

Comment: No Brasil é pronunciado pe.ríu.do.

Comment: Não, @Jacinto, não rima.

Comment: @ANeves Inclui links à pronunciação de várias palavras. Vê lá se tu pronuncias *período* e *míudo* como eles.

Comment: @AndréLyra Incluí links a sites onde podes ouvir as palavras serem pronunciadas, por portugueses e brasileiros. Vê lá se eles pronunciam como tu.

Comment: @Jacinto não, parece que não.

Comment: @ANeves Tens que adicionar a tua própria gravação, para termos um repertório completo. Mas parece-te que que na pronúncia deles *período* rima com *miúdo*? Ou sou só eu?

Comment: pe.ríu.do e mi.ú.do são pronúncias totalmente diferentes. Se fosse escrito periodo sem acento a pronúncia mudaria para pe.ri.ô.do ou pe.rio.dô

Comment: De certa forma rima, Jacinto. Como explica [o artigo no CiberDúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/periodo/7124) que *linkaste*, tem a ver com onde pões a sílaba tónica. Eu ponho no i; tu pões no o; na leitura não consigo ter a certeza... as fronteiras estão um pouco esbatidas.

Comment: @ANeves Eu tive que me esforçar para pronunciar com acento no ***i***. Tive que pensar em *varíola*, e fica a palavra mais comprida.  Eu ponho a acentuação no ***o*** mas tenho primeiro que o transformar em ***u***. Se não, rimava com [*iodo*](http://pt.forvo.com/word/iodo/#pt)

Answer (score 3):

Parece-me que é simplesmente uma daquelas palavras que (em Lisboa) muita gente pronucia como paroxítonas, apesar de tradicionalmente o não serem, tal como [*Úrano*](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/afinal-e-urano-ou-urano/11725) e [*clítoris*](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/clitorisclitoris/7635) (em Portugal). Simplesmente parece que essa pronúncia não está ainda generalizada ao ponto de ser dicionarizada.

O fenómeno parece estender-se a pelo menos uma outra palavra terminada em *íodo*: *díodo*, que creio (já lá vão alguns anos ) ser pronunciado /di.'o.du/ pelos meus professores da faculdade. Palavras terminadas em *íolo* como *vitríolo* e *folíolo* não parecem sofrer o mesmo efeito.

Comment: Encontrei sobre o assunto [este artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/periodo/7124) e [este](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-acento-grafico-de-periodo/33541) e mais [este](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/gratuito-periodo-madail-juiz/1856). Vão mais ou menos de encontro ao que tu dizes.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com acordo ortográfico a palavra "período" é escrita com acento no i, visto que ao pronunciá-la, o locutor carrega no i.

A pronúncia do 'u' é notavelmente mais grave que a do 'o', por isso, usar a palavra "periúdo" notaria-se a diferença em relação a "período" principalmente no 'iu'

Outro ponto de vista, seria que o facto de o 'i' levar acento significa que essa vogal 'í' é pronunciada de forma mais prolongada, assim como 'ú'. Ou seja, ao pronunciar a palavra "periúdo" ouviria-se mais acentuadamente o 'u' que o resto das letras

Comment: Experimentaste a ouvir as pessoas a pronunciar *período, miúdo, varíola* nos links na minha pergunta? Ao meu ouvido, da maneira como elas pronunciam (que é como eu pronuncio e estou habituado a ouvir), *período* rima com *miúdo*. Ou seja o ***io*** de *período* parece-me ser  pronunciado como o ***iu*** de *miúdo* e não como o ***io*** de *varíola*. Estou curioso em saber se sou só eu, ou se as outras pessoas também ouvem assim.

Comment: Eu noto certa diferença, até porque o ú de 'miúdo' tem mais prolongação do que o 'o' de 'período'

Comment: E achas que nesses links  ***io*** de *período* é pronunicado mais proximamente do ***iu*** de *miúdo* ou do ***io*** de *varíola*? (As três palavras são pronunciadas nos links.)

Comment: Acho que a pronúncia aproxima-se mais de «varíola». Espero que não esteja errado.