# Por que não existem palavras como "júniores" na língua portuguesa, semelhante à fonética da língua italiana?

Tags: estrangeirismos, acentuação, fonética

Como podemos entender o porquê do não haver acento em uma palavra semelhante à suposta "júniores", como existe o som da primeira sílaba parecido em língua italiana, ainda mais que dizemos "Júnior" e não "juniôr"?

Na língua portuguesa dizemos que uma palavra é oxítona, ou paroxítona ou proparoxítona. No caso que citei, como chamamos ao acento na primeira das quatro sílabas, que é usado em outros idiomas?

Comment: Interessante. Acho que essa pergunta nunca me ocorreu.

Comment: Este é um dos casos em que existe a palavra oficial, *juniores*, paroxítona, mas que muita gente pronuncia como se fosse *júniores*, sobre-esdrúxula; na prática, como este *io* é pronunciado como ditongo crescente, fica simplesmente esdrúxula (proparoxítona). Há outros casos assim: oficialmente é *míope*, mas creio que toda a gente pronuncia como se fosse *miúpe*, e [*período*, como se fosse *periúdo*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1814/porqu%c3%aa-per%c3%adodo-e-n%c3%a3o-peri%c3%bado). >>

Comment: No caso de *juniores*, a divergência deve-se provavelmente ao plural ser irregular, e o pessoa cria um plural regular. Além de *sénior - seniores*, que é paralelo, só conheço outro caso em que a sílaba tónica muda, *caráter - carateres*.

Comment: Eu sempre digo míope, miopia, com som de (ô). Eu digo período como "perildo".

Comment: Eu acho que muita gente diz **os junior** sem s.

Comment: **Uma coisa é texto escrito, outra é como o pessoal fala**. Quem vai pronunciar o es em júniores??